# Configuring Solr on remote server using SIM

Tags: solr, sim

Is it possible to configure Solr using SIM on a remote machine?
By default it shows http://localhost:8983/solr .Can we have it something as http://abc.com:8983/solr ?

Comment: I don't believe there would be a good way for SIM to handle that. You can however use the reverse proxy approach. http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/06/17/lockdown-solr-with-iis-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: Another option is to update the Sitecore package file with the config changes and use that modified zip to build your instances using SIM.